# Android Room auto Timestamp with OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE

Tags: android, android-room

Does the Room have auto timestamp support? For example, my table has only two fields. One is a string `"ABC"`, the second is auto timestamp. The exact same line appears `"ABC"` then `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` replace first string and adds a new timestamp, with a fresh date. Is it possible for ROOM?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know built-in way for update. For new row's insert  you can set [default value](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo#defaultValue()) for timestamp field, but that don't help with updates.

You can try next approaches (I'm not sure they could be called `auto-timestamp`):

1. Use additional method in Dao, emulating `auto-timestamp`:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)  
fun insertAndUpdateTimestamp(foo: Foo)

fun insert(foo: Foo) { // <-- should be called from outside (Repository etc)
    foo.updated = [here set timestamp's value you need] // <-- updated - is timestamp field
    insertAndUpdateTimestamp(foo)
}
```

Row updates if in `foo` instance there is the same Primary Key as already exists in DB (string Primary Key in your example - "ABC").

2. Approach with Sqlite triggers (create trigger, that updates needed field on each insert/update). [Here](https://proandroiddev.com/sqlite-triggers-android-room-2e7120bb3e3a) is some article describing triggers in Room.